# Advanced logical query in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, yii

I have a logical expression:

```
( Ts == <lastTs> && Id > <lastId> ) || Ts > <_lastTs>
```

Where Ts and Id are the collection's fields and  and  are variables.

I am using Yii Mongodb suite so I cannot use "$or" operator as it is not implemented.

So I changed that statement into:

```
!(!( Ts == <lastTs> && Id > <lastId> ) && Ts <= <lastTs> )
```

Is it possible to run something like this in Mongo?

I tried to construct something but I noticed when I do for example:

```
"$not": {
  "created_at": {"$lte": ISODate("...")},
  "_id": {"$gte": MongoID(...)}
}
```

It does not return any result. But when I remove "$not" it returns some data. I am not sure if it's allowed to used $not on field.

Is there a way to run such query in Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a complex criteria using EMongoCriteria::setConditions(). It accepts any kind of array as parameters and EMongoDocument::find() will pass it unchanged to PHP's Mongo extension.

Try this:

```
$c = new EMongoCriteria;
$c->setConditions([ '$or' => [ 
                    'created_at' => ['$gt' => ... ],
                    '$and' => [
                        '_id' => ['$gt' => ... ],
                        'created_at' => ['$eq' => ...]
                     ]
                   ] 
                ]);
$documents = MyCollection::model()->find($c);
```